# Load testing an application that uses Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, load-testing, ddos

Our client has implemented Google Maps in their applications and we are working with them on a large scale load test. Our concern is that Google may interpret this test as a denial-of-service attack and shut out the application. With this in mind, I have three questions:

- Is this an issue? Meaning, is Google likely to lock out our application during a test that might have 50,000 simultaneous users?
- If this an issue, is there anyone we can chat with to get "pre-approval" of the apps during the testing period to make sure this doesn't happen.
- Alternatively, does Google offer a version of their API for testing purposes? (I could not find any information in the documentation)

Please note that we are also exploring other solutions (excluding the calls from the app, stubbing out the API, etc).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I assume you have read this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage_limits, which states: "The maximum billable limit defaults to 1 000 000 map loads per day. You can change this limit by clicking the Set billable limits button on the Quotas page of the console. Higher limits are available on request". I doubt that Google would notice 50,000 simultaneous users (based on having implemented my own WMTS server at work) in terms of load, but it is good that there is an official mechanism to ensure you are playing by the rules, and not get cut off during testing.

Answer (score 2):

Running the load test on the page that implements google maps may result in a  bill or having maps turned off if you reach the daily limit of requests.

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/